# Multiple variations of a certain email campaign. How to determine the winner?

Tags: multiple-regression

I have run 5 variations for my email campaign with small changes in the subject line for each variation. What statistical method can I use to determine the winner among these 5 variations? Each variation has 500 recipients and the open rates for each of the variation is as follows: 1 (10.2%), 2 (14%), 3 (7%), 4 (14.2%), 5 (15%).

Is there a statistical method I can use to compare each of the variations against the rest and tell me the winning campaign statistically?

Comment: The winner obviously is the one with the greatest return.  What, then, do you mean by "statistically"?

Comment: Sorry. Let me change the scenario a little bit. If the number of recipients were also different in each of the variations and its not possible for me to run the test anymore, then how do I reach a statistical conclusion? 

Eg. Lets say the data was something like this: 
Var 1. 100 recipients 10.2% open
Var 2. 400 recipients 14% open
Var 1. 200 recipients 7% open
Var 1. 500 recipients 14.2% open
Var 1. 300 recipients 15% open

Comment: Well, the way to account for the fact that there are different numbers of people in the different groups is to use the relative numbers. Exactly what you have already done.  
What you could do is note that the top 3 rates are very similar (14%, 14,2% and 15%). You could validate these results by running another trial with just these 3 results and see if the ordering holds.

Comment: If I can't run the trial again, can I use something like Chi Squared or ANOVA analysis to figure out whether Variation 5 is statistically the winner even though the base number for each of the variants is different?